# Guitar tablature: same fret indication connected by arc, no label

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature

I'm trying to learn "Hard Time Killin' Floor Blues", by Skip James, and I am stumped on the circled notation in the picture. It doesn’t look like a pull off or hammer on to me, because the fret number is the same in the arc notation.

[image]

Comment: Hope you don’t mind, I touched up your image a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The 3^3 is called a tie, it simply means you play the first note, hold it and let it ring into the next note, where you simultaneously play the open E string.

BTW your tab diagram seems to be missing two strings, maybe its’s a low resolution copy?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "tie".

> a curved line connecting the heads of two notes of the same pitch, indicating that they are to be played as a single note with a duration equal to the sum of the individual notes' values. ([SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(music)))

The tie is required to make clear that the note should be held through the articulation of the next rhythmic moment.